# Reshaping Data with Multiple Sets of Column Variables

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape some of my data and haven't had any luck with the reshape2 package.  Nothing I've tried is quite what I'm looking for given my data.

I have a data.frame that looks like this (where name1 corresponds to age1, and name2 corresponds to age2, etc):

```
city <- c("New York", "Philadelphia", "Chicago")
state <- c("NY", "PA", "IL")
name1 <- c("Tim", NA, NA)
name2 <- c("Bob", "Jim", "Bill")
name3 <- c(NA, NA, "Jeff")
age1 <- c(40, NA, NA)
age2 <- c(30, 29, 34)
age3 <- c(NA, NA, 27)

df <- data.frame(city, state, name1, name2, name3, age1, age2, age3)

          city state name1 name2 name3 age1 age2 age3
1     New York    NY   Tim   Bob  <NA>   40   30   NA
2 Philadelphia    PA  <NA>   Jim  <NA>   NA   29   NA
3      Chicago    IL  <NA>  Bill  Jeff   NA   34   27
```

In my actual data set, I have about 50 "name" and "age" variables each.

Ultimately, I'm aiming for 4 variables:  city, state, name, age.  I also don't want the NA's in my finished data set.  So what I'm looking to achieve is this:

```
          city state name age
1     New York    NY  Tim  40
2     New York    NY  Bob  30
3 Philadelphia    PA  Jim  29
4      Chicago    IL Bill  34
5      Chicago    IL Jeff  27
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've tried the reshape2 and tidyR packages, but no luck yet!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using base R functions, you can do

```
subset(reshape(df, list(paste0("name", 1:3), paste0("age", 1:3)), 
    v.names=c("name","age"),
    direction="long"), !is.na(name), select=-c(time, id))
```

to get

```
            city state name age
1.1     New York    NY  Tim  40
1.2     New York    NY  Bob  30
2.2 Philadelphia    PA  Jim  29
3.2      Chicago    IL Bill  34
3.3      Chicago    IL Jeff  27
```

Comment: Interesting that `reshape(df[1:5],varying=3:5, direction="long", sep="")` correctly guesses `name` from `name1/2/3`, but `reshape(df,varying=list(3:5,6:8), direction="long", sep="")` ballses it up and guesses `name1` and `age1` from `name1/2/3` and `age1/2/3` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

`melt` from "reshape2" presently can't handle this nicely since the "name" and "age" columns are of different types. However, a later version of "data.table" (which will also implement melt) will let you do such a transformation by supplying a `list` of the measure variables. (See [Issue #828](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/828), which has the feature launching in V1.9.8 of "data.table".)

In the meantime, other than `reshape` in base R, you can also try `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
na.omit(merged.stack(df, var.stubs = c("name", "age"), sep = "var.stubs"))
#            city state .id .t1 name age
# 1:      Chicago    IL   2   2 Bill  34
# 2:      Chicago    IL   3   3 Jeff  27
# 3:     New York    NY   1   1  Tim  40
# 4:     New York    NY   2   2  Bob  30
# 5: Philadelphia    PA   2   2  Jim  29
```

`sep = "var.stubs"` is a way of saying that there is no separator between the variable stub and the "time" of measurement.

If you also wanted to drop the unnecessary columns, you can compound that into the previous statement (or use `subset` as @MrFlick did).

```
na.omit(
  merged.stack(df, var.stubs = c("name", "age"), 
               sep = "var.stubs")[, c(
                 "city", "state", "name", "age"), with = FALSE])
#            city state name age
# 1:      Chicago    IL Bill  34
# 2:      Chicago    IL Jeff  27
# 3:     New York    NY  Tim  40
# 4:     New York    NY  Bob  30
# 5: Philadelphia    PA  Jim  29
```

Comment: Dang, I was hoping you would appear and solve my `reshape` issue from my comment on MrFlick's post. Alas, poor old `reshape` didn't bring home the bacon this time.

Comment: @thelatemail, isn't your `reshape` issue solved by specifying `v.names`? I agree it seems odd that it works with one approach but not the other though.

Comment: It is, but I was sure I'd seen you make `reshape` work without directly specifying `v.names=`. I guess I imagined that part.

Comment: @thelatemail, maybe you are thinking of my lazy approach: `reshape(df, direction = "long", varying = 3:ncol(df), sep = "")`. `list` is only really required when the columns might be in different orders, if I remember correctly....

Comment: @thelatemail, This monkey has hit the correct key. Do I get a reward or a shock?

Comment: As with any good psych. grad, it has to be the shock I turn to first. Off to the [Skinner box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinner_box) with you!